# Viewport shading has no light even though there's light

Tags: 3d-view, light

The viewport shading is just grey, with no light even though there are a few lamps in the viewport. Can anyone explain why?
As you can see, the black vertical line down the middle is the sun lamp

[image]

EDIT: I couldn't find out the problem, but I just exported the model into another blender file and it was fine there.

Comment: If you have an AMD GPU it's your graphics drivers. Try enabling "High Quality Normals" Under _Render Properties_ > _Performance_ and if that doesn't work, roll back your graphics drivers to an earlier  version.

Comment: are you in the Material Preview or render Mode? The 4 buttons top right.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Doubt it, its fine in other projects. It's just this project thats doing it. Maybe I accidentally triggered something?

Comment: @Phönix64 Render Preview

Comment: Does it work if you render it out trough F12

Comment: @Phönix64 Yeah it does

Comment: I couldn't find out the problem, but I just exported the model into another blender file and it was fine there.